# Get div children ids

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div which contains other divs like this:

```
<div id="main_div">

  <div id="div_1">
    <div id="some_id"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_2">
    <div id="some_id"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_3">
    <div id="some_id"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can programatically get the next div id when a particular div is clicked?

```
div_1 is clicked -> alert div_2
div_2 is clicked -> alert div_3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you should do it like this.
Using the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function

```
$("#main_div > div").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).next("div").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: And the jQuery tag is where?

Comment: not here. heh well ill assume hes using it until i get voted down into oblivion

Comment: "#main_div div" should be changed to "#main_div > div"

Answer (score 0):

You coud use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling)

> Returns the node immediately following the specified one in its parent's childNodes list, or null if the specified node is the last node in that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById('main_div');

for (var i=0, len=div.children.length; i<len; i++) {
    div.children[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var nextSib = e.target.nextSibling;

        if (nextSib) alert(nextSib.id);
    }, false);
}
```